# Putting UITabbarController inside UINavigationController. What problem may occur?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a stack like below hierarchy (I'm using programatic way, so I done it)

```
UINavigationController -> UITabbarController -> UInavigationController -> UIViewController
                                             -> UInavigationController -> UIViewController
```

As Apple Docs say for `pushViewController`:

> The view controller to push onto the stack. This object cannot be a tab bar controller

I need to know If this has a known bug or will CERTAINLY causes a bug.

I really searched a lot for similar posts but none of them give me an acceptable answer.
[Using UITabBarController with UINavigationController - Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41567013/using-uitabbarcontroller-with-uinavigationcontroller-swift-3)

[Can you push a UITabBarController inside an UINavigationController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822160/can-you-push-a-uitabbarcontroller-inside-an-uinavigationcontroller)

Comment: Neither it causes a bug, nor it is a bug.
It's just that apple wants you to have different stacks for different tabs in your tab bar controller.
Although the above mentioned stack can still be achieved but is not recommended and it is not the right way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It would be awesome If we can some answer from official/credible sources.

Comment: Posted a referrence from apple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

From [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/TabBarControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH3-SW2):

> Before creating a tab bar interface, you need to decide how you intend
>   to use a tab bar interface. Because it imposes an overarching
>   organization on your data,you should use one only in these specific
>   ways:
>
> - Install it directly as a window’s root view controller.
> - Install it as
>     one of the two view controllers in a split view interface. (iPad only)
> - Present it modally from another view controller.
> - Display it from a
>     popover. (iPad only)
>
> Installing a tab bar interface in your app’s main
>   window is by far the most common way to use it.
>   In such a scenario,
>   the tab bar interface provides the fundamental organizing principle
>   for your app’s data, with each tab leading the user to a distinct part
>   of the app. You can use tab bar controllers by themselves or in
>   conjunction with other view controllers to create even more
>   sophisticated interfaces. For more information, see Combined View
>   Controller Interfaces.
>
> It is also possible to present a tab bar controller modally if a very
>   specific need makes doing so worthwhile. For example, you could
>   present a tab bar controller modally in order to edit some complex
>   data set that had several distinct sets of options. Because a modal
>   view fills all or most of the screen (depending on the device), the
>   presence of the tab bar would simply reflect the choices available for
>   viewing or editing the modally presented data. Avoid using a tab bar
>   in this way if a simpler design approach is available.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I still curious about why we can't use it.

Comment: As it says you can use it, but it is not recommended by apple. 
Most of the apple users are used to have the tab bar as the root controller.

Comment: As I understand they say "u can use it but we don't recommend it" for presenting tab bar modally. In my case, I use pushViewController and in pushViewController's doc It says "you cannot"